# Make external monitor the "Main Display" after turning on "Display have separate Spaces"

Tags: display

I want to turn on "Displays have separate Spaces" (mainly because I have heard that this can deal with the lagging issue). However, once I turn this option on, the Menu Bar on top and the Dock can only be displayed on my laptop screen, instead of on both monitors. I wonder if there's a way to make them display on my external monitor only.

Comment: This sounds like the correct behaviour for when you switch separate Spaces *off*, not on.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In **Displays** → **Arrangement**, the Menu Bar shows as a white strip and it suffices to move that strip between monitors.